# Help identifying potentially two LEGO sets - Hogwart's and Star Wars?

Tags: set-identification

I just received a LEGO Eiffel Tower set from a very generous neighbor.  With the set, she included two other bags of LEGO pieces just in case the Eiffel Tower set was not complete and had pieces of it in those two bags.  Well, those two bags also included some of these pieces that were already created.  One of them appears to be Hogwart's Castle.  However, I am not sure what the other set might be.  Do any of these pieces look familiar to anyone (particularly the set that looks like it may be a Star Wars set)?  Thanks!

[image: Potentially two sets]

Answer (score 14):

You’re correct that the one set looks like Hogwarts. Specifically [5378 Hogwarts Castle (3rd edition)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5378-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D). There are three [Dolores Umbridge figures](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=dolores%20umbridge#T=M), only one with solid pink legs like in your photo. This version only appears in the 3rd edition Hogwarts.

[image: Hogwarts set photo from Bricklink]

The Star Wars set looks like [8039 Venator-Class Republic Attack Cruiser](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8039-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).

[image: Venator set photo from Bricklink]

Neither set contains [Boat, 14 x 5 x 2 with Oarlocks without Hollow Inside Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=21301&name=Boat,%2014%20x%205%20x%202%20with%20Oarlocks%20without%20Hollow%20Inside%20Studs&category=%5BBoat%5D#T=C) though it does appear in [75954 Hogwarts Great Hall](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75954-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) so it could reasonably be part of the collection of someone interested in Harry Potter sets.

[image: Boat image from Bricklink]